# Simplify multiple nested if()'s

Tags: php, conditional-statements, nested-if

Can someone help me simplify this complex nested `if()`'s algorithm? I know it can be simplified, but I'm afraid I'll mess up with the multiple conditions if I trust myself.

```
$groups = array();

foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item['group_code']) {
        if (array_key_exists($item['group_code'], $groups)) {
            if (mb_strlen($groups[$item['group_code']]) < mb_strlen($item['title'])) {
                $groups[$item['group_code']] = $item['title'];
            }
        } else {
            $groups[$item['group_code']] = $item['title'];
        }
    } else {
        $groups[$item['item_code']] = $item['title'];
    }
}
```

What I want is to create an index of product titles in `$groups`. If the `group_code` key exists for each item, then I want to store the lengthier title of all items belonging to that group. If `group_code` doesn't exist (meaning it's a single product and not a grouped one), I want to store the title of that item using the `item_code` instead (this is the simplest condition, and no length comparison is needed here).

Comment: it looks like `else` is missing for innermost `if`

Comment: @IłyaBursov no it doesn't! `if (mb_strlen($groups[$item['group_code']]) >= mb_strlen($item['title']))` then nothing should happen!

Comment: @FayeD.  "If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. Here's [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Then return here and do the same with the tick/check-mark till it turns green. This informs the community, that a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about checking the `else` conditions first?

```php
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if (!isset($item['group_code'])){
        $groups[$item['item_code']] = $item['title'];
    } else if (!array_key_exists($item['group_code'], $groups)){
        $groups[$item['group_code']] = $item['title'];
    } else if (mb_strlen($groups[$item['group_code']]) < mb_strlen($item['title'])){
        $groups[$item['group_code']] = $item['title'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I'll go with this route as it find it quite similar in regards to its complexity to mine, but this one is more compact. I'll mark it as the solution once I check it produces the same results as mine though.

Comment: You can simplify this even more.

Answer (score 2):

I'd simplify it like this (php 7+):

```php
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $t = $item['title'];
    $c = $item['group_code'] ?? $item['item_code'];
    if (mb_strlen($t) > mb_strlen($groups[$c] ?? '')) $groups[$c] = $t;
}
```

Comment: It's very late here, so I can't figure out your algorithm as my eyes are already closing, but tomorrow I'll look into it more carefully. Though it seems a bit more complex than mine (or maybe my brain got so tired). I'll be back! Thanks anyway! :)